# How to plot top %1 in different color in a scatter plotting?

Tags: python, plot, conditional-statements, scatter

I have two columns consist numeric numbers in a .csv file.
Let's imagine

column1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 3, 14, 7, 9]

column2 = [2, 5, 2, 67, 8, 3, 6, 5, 2]

column1 and column2 are basically time series but there is no index number in the csv file.
I would like to plot values that are at top %1 in different colors.

So, my code is

```
features = ['column1' , 'column2']
df = pd.read_csv('XX.csv', usecols=features, sep=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
for features in df:
    new_df = df[[features]].quantile(q=.99, axis=0, numeric_only=True).iloc[0]
```

This code produces two threshold numbers for each column that represents the top %1 of each column. And the next step is that plotting a scatter plot for a and b columns and if the number is above these two thresholds for each column, show it in a different color.
I messed up here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your dataframe to specify the colours under certain conditions. Here I've interpreted your requirements to mean that if either `column1` or `column2` is over its respective threshold, then it gets a different colour. I have hardcoded the thresholds to make the code easier to read; you would probably use `new_df["column1"]` and `new_df["column2"]` in the conditions.

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 3, 14, 7, 9],
    "column2": [2, 5, 2, 67, 8, 3, 6, 5, 2]
}) # set up test df
dftest["colour"] = "green" # put green everywhere in the new colour column
dftest.loc[(dftest["column1"] > 13.6) | (dftest["column2"] > 62),"colour"] = "red" # overwrite with red where you need to.
dftest.plot.scatter(x="column1", y="column2", c=dftest["colour"])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. However, what if we have more than two columns. Imagine there are 15 columns like this and we should do show it on the confusion matrix?

Comment: I think I managed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Since you're a new user, I hope you don't mind me pointing out what's considered good etiquette on this site: if I answered your question as asked (and it only mentioned 2 columns, not 15), then please consider giving an upvote and/or accepting the answer.